# How to correctly format a PHP foreach loop?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo, highcharts

I have a PHP PDO query, it selects the year, month and day from the database. It also counts the number of rows that each day has:

```
    SELECT  
    dateYear, dateMonth, dateDay, 
    count(dateDay) AS count_days
    FROM just_ink 
    WHERE dateMonth = :month AND dateYear = :year AND deleted = 0  
    GROUP BY dateYear, dateMonth, dateDay
```

When echoing the results:

```
 foreach ($result as $subResult) {
     foreach ($subResult as $row) {
        $year = $row['dateYear'];
        $month = $row['dateMonth'];
        $day = $row['dateDay'];
        $count = $row['count_days'];
        echo $month . " " . $day . " " . $year . " " . $count . " lines, ";
    }
}
```

This returns a value like:

```
June 7 2016 3 lines, June 8 2016 1 lines,
```

This means, June 7th has 3 forms and June 8th has 1 form.

Now for the formatting, I am using [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic) basic line chart. The data needs to be formatted in this way:

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
    title: {
        text: 'Monthly New Forms',
        x: -20 //center
    },
    xAxis: {
    title: {
                text: 'Day of the Month'
    },
        categories: [
        '1', '2', '3', '4', '5',
        '6', '7', '8', '9', '10',
        '11', '12', '13', '14', '15',
        '16', '17', '18', '19', '20',
        '21', '22', '23', '24', '25',
        '26', '27', '28', '29', '30',
        '31' 
        ]
    },
    yAxis: {
        title: {
            text: 'Month of June'
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 1,
            color: '#808080'
        }]
    },
    tooltip: {

    },
    legend: {
        layout: 'vertical',
        align: 'right',
        verticalAlign: 'middle',
        borderWidth: 0
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Number of New Forms Per Day',
        data: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
    }]
});
});
</script>
```

Where the categories are the x-axis titles, and the series data is the frequency of each day. So If I want to represent

```
June 7 2016 3 lines, June 8 2016 1 lines,
```

The series data would need to look like

```
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, etc.
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Build an array the way highcharts wants it and use `json_encode()` to send it to javascript.

Comment: @jeroen how do you "build" an array?

Comment: As @jeroen said, make a php array (or associative array specifically) and pass that into an echo json_encode. More info here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create an array with elements for every day of the month:

```
$counts = array_fill(1, 31, 0);
```

Then in your loop, fill in the entry for the day:

```
foreach ($subresult as $row) {
    $day = $row['dateDay'];
    $counts[$day] = $row['count_days'];
}
$counts = array_values($counts); // because json_encode treats it as an object if indexes don't start at 0
echo json_encode($counts);
```

I'm not sure why you're selecting `dateYear` and `dateMonth`, since those are the inputs to the query. You don't need to set those variables in the loop, since they'll always be the same thing.

Comment: This seems to have worked, result is [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"3","1",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]
But, it seems to have added 1 zero, so where "3" is supposed to be on the 7th int it is on the 8th

Comment: I changed the starting element from 0 to 1. I'm so used to 0-based arrays, but that's not right for days of the month.

Comment: Adding 2 lines of code made this work: unset($counts[0]); AND $counts = array_values($counts);  Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: Didn't changing the starting index in `array_fill` solve the problem? Why set something if you're just going to unset it later?

Comment: You could also use `array_shift($counts)` to remove the first element.

Answer (score 0):

```
$highchartdata = []

foreach ($subResult as $row) {
    $highchartdata[$row['dateDay']] = $row['count_days'];
  }

echo json_encode($highchartdata);
```

get the above json data from server

```
 obj = JSON.parse(data);// parse the json data
 for (i = 1; i <=31; i++) { 
    if(!obj[i]) // if ith key is not defined make it 0
     obj[i]=0;
  }

console.log(obj);
```

Comment: echo json_encode(#highchartsdata); 

this echos: {"7":"3","8":"1"} 

but in the console log : "Uncaught ReferenceError: data is not defined"